# gwt notify specifics clients

Tags: gwt, client, notify

Hie,

I'am actually using gwt for my app, but may be it's not a gwt related question:
I have some users which can send message to other users (connected or not), i'd like to notify the recipient (and only this recipient) he has received one message, i'd like to know the best approach to do this?

Any idea is welcome.

i like the comet approach, but i'am not sure i can handle the constraint that only the recepient should be notified (not other connected users)

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, sorry to up the topic...

First of all, I assume that GWT app is Web app (client/server architecture)

AFAIK, there is 2 options:

The comet approach is more like the push method, the server hold connections for each clients so when a user send a notification to the server, the server could dispatch it to the related client(s).

The other method is polling the server, it doesn't know any clients, it gives data to whoever ask for, so all clients has just to ask repeatedly for new data. Your server just need to hold data and deliver them when the corresponding client asks.

So every thing depends on what you need...